# How can I get AVAudioEngine to output PCM-16 from the Mic?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I'm using `AVAudioEngine` and I'm trying to get it to output `.pcmFormatInt16` at 16000Hz but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I'm doing:

```
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
let input = self.audioEngine.inputNode!

audioEngine.attach(mixer)
audioEngine.connect(input, to: mixer, format: input.outputFormat(forBus: 0))

let recordingFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 16000.0, channels: 1, interleaved: true)

mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 2048, format: recordingFormat) { [weak self] (buffer, _) in
    // buffer here is all 0's!
}

self.audioEngine.prepare()
try! self.audioEngine.start()
```

As noted above, when I access the buffer it is always all 0, silence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVAudioEngine don't supports changing sample rate.
You can use AVAudioConverter to change sample rate like that

```
let inputFormat = input.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
let recordingFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 16000.0, channels: 1, interleaved: true)
converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: recordingFormat)

mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 2048, format: inputFormat) { [weak self] (buffer, _) in
    let convertedBuffer = self?.converter.convertBuffer(additionalBuffer: buffer)
}
```

Comment: You can change the sample rate just by changing the format of the connection, but not all formats are supported that way.

Comment: If you change sample rate by connection format, it looks like changed sample rate, but sound has noise. For example, changing sample rate 48000 to 44100 in iPhone6s, buffer sounds is slower than record.